# Ruby 2.0 - Rounding an integer to the nearest multiple of 10

Tags: ruby, rounding

How do i round an integer to the nearest multiple of ten?

I have tried `integer.round(0.1)` but it gives the nearest *decimal* number.

Example: 3 should return 0, 55 should return 60.

Is there a method that will round to the nearest multiple of 10?

Comment: `10*((x+5)/10)` would work for non-negative integers.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

[Integer#round](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Integer.html#method-i-round) has the functionality.

You pass a negative number to `round` to represent which 10's digit you'd want to round to.  For example:

Round to the nearest 10:

```
55.round(-1) # => 60
```

To round to the nearest 100:

```
550.round(-2) # => 600
```

Comment: This will round to one significant figure and not necessarily to 'tens' precision.

Comment: Ohh... So i make the number _negative_. Thank you!

Comment: @AaronCronin I didn't get you.. :(

Comment: Nevermind, I am incorrect and this works fine! I misread the documentation :)

Comment: No, sorry. I only use Vim for coding.

Comment: @AaronCronin Vim? I use Sublime Text! P.S.: Just wanted to get in the conversation.

Comment: @Davesexcel Take time to read the question and have focus on OPs needs, then ask in reply.

Answer (score 14):

You can just divide by 10, round, then multiply by 10:

```
nearest = (x/ 10).round * 10
```

Comment: `(15/10).round * 10` returns `10` but should have returned `20`.

Comment: That's just because of integer division truncating the decimal, if you divide by `10.0` instead it will round to 20.

Comment: If you want to round down no matter what (this was a requirement for me),  you could do (x / 10.0).floor * 10

Comment: @sixty4bit Why not `x / 10 * 10` then?

Comment: @x-yuri `x / 10 * 10` always returns `x`.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen `5 / 10 * 10 == 0`, `9 / 10 * 10 == 0`, Looks pretty much like `floor` to me. Also, `0.1 ** 323 / 10 * 10 == 0.0`

Comment: @x-yuri didnt realize you were specifically talking about integer division.